# By Using Dropdown how to Show/Hide the images

Tags: javascript, html, parental-control

I am trying to create a car rental form to calculate the order sheet.

My question is when the user selects the car type from a list box or drop-down list it should work with the image.

```
<form width="900px" height="900>
      <center><h1><span class="alternate-font">Rent a Car</span></h1></center>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

            $('#dropDown').change(function () {
                $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide()
                $('#' + this.value).show();

            });
        </script>
        <select id="dropDown">
            <option>Choose a Car</option>
            <option value="comp">Compact Car - $29.99</option>
            <option value="mid">Midsize Car - $39.99</option>
            <option value="lux">Luxury Car - $49.99</option>
        </select>
        <div id="comp" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/economy.png" alt="" width="300px" height="200px"/></div>
        <div id="mid" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/Midsize.png" alt="" width="300px" height="150px"/></div>
        <div id="mid" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/luxury.png" alt="" width="300px" height="150px"/></div>
        <br>
        <select name="cars">
            <option>Select Your City</option>
            <option value="sfo">San Francisco</option>
            <option value="la">Los Angeles</option>
            <option value="lux">Luxury</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is move the script right before the ending body tag in your html, and at the very least after the HTML of your dropdown menu.

What is happening right now is that the script is executing before the dropdown is even being added to the DOM. Thus, your event

```
$('#dropDown').change(function () {
```

and any element you are binding does not exist.

Also, two minor errors you want to change in your code:

1.

```
<form width="900px" height="900>
```

There needs to be a closing quote after height. I suggest using a nice text editor with JS capabilities to check that for you.

2.

```
<div id="comp" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/economy.png" alt="" width="300px" height="200px"/></div>
<div id="mid" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/Midsize.png" alt="" width="300px" height="150px"/></div>
<div id="mid" class="drop-down-show-hide"><img src="img/luxury.png" alt="" width="300px" height="150px"/></div>
```

Make sure id's are unique. In this case the 2nd and 3rd element share the same id, which will cause element selection issues.